# How to translate and migrate data

Tags: php, csv, ms-access, data-migration

I am building php web application that let's a user upload a MS Access Database (csv export) that is then translated and migrated into a MySQL database.

The MS Access database consists of one table called t_product of 100k rows.  This table is not designed well.  As an example, the following query:

```
SELECT part_number, model_number FROM t_product
```

will return:

```
part_number model_number
100  AX1000, AX1001, AX1002
101  CZ10, CZ220, MB100
```

As you can see, the model numbers are listed as comma separated values instead of individual records in another table.  There are many more issues of this nature.   I'm writing a script to clean this data before importing into the mysql database.  The script will also map existing Access columns to a proper relationally design database.

My issue is that my script takes too long to complete. Here's simplified code to explain what I'm doing:

```
$handle = fopen("MSAccess.csv, "r");

// get each row from the csv
while ($data=fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))
{
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO t_product (col1, col2 etc...) values ($data[0], $data[1], etc...");
 $prodId = mysql_last_insert_id();

 // using model as an example, there are other columns
 // with csv values that need to be broken up
 $arrModel = explode(',', $data[2]);
 foreach($arrModel as $modelNumber)
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO t_model (product_id, col1, col2 etc...) values ($prodId, $modelNumber[0], $modelNumber[1] etc...");
}
```

The problem here is that each while-loop iteration makes a tremendous  number of calls to the database.  For every product record, I have to insert N model numbers, Y part numbers, X serial numbers etc...

I started another approach where I stored the whole CSV in an array.  I then write one batch query like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO t_product (col1, col2, etc...) values ";
foreach($arrParam as $val)
 $sql .= " ($val[0], $val[1], $val[2]), "
```

But I ran into excessive memory errors with this approach.  I increased the max memory limit to 64M and I'm still running out of memory.

What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Maybe I should write all my queries to a *.sql file first, then import the *.sql file into the mysql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write all my queries into a .SQL file.  This gave me the opportunity to normalize the CSV file into a proper relational database.  Afterwards, my php script called an exec("mysql -h dbserver.com -u myuser -pmypass dbname < db.sql");

This solved my memory problems and it was much faster than multiple queries from php.

Answer (score 1):

This may be entirely not the direction you want to go, but you can generate the MySQL creation script directly from MS Access with the free [MySQL Migration Toolkit](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)

Perhaps you could allow the user to upload the Access db, and then have your PHP script call the Migration toolkit?

Comment: The migration toolkit will also optimize its queries somewhat to speedup the bulk translation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to try optimizing the code you have there already, I would try aggregating the INSERTS and see if that helps. This should be easy to add to your code. Something like this (C# pseudocode):

```
int flushCount = 0;

while (!done)
{
    // Build next query, concatenate to last set of queries

    if (++flushCount == 5)
    {
        // Flush queries to database

        // Reset query string to empty

        flushCount = 0;
    }
}

// Flush remaining queries to the database
```